# Program getting elif messed up

Tags: python, python-2.7

rock paper scissors code. supposed to choose a random one and put it against a user inputed choice, it works sometimes but others on the same possibility where it should be the same it changes outcomes

```
    import random       
def one_game():
    score_bot = 0
    score_player = 0
    a = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    UI = raw_input('(enter your choice rock, paper, or scissors)')
    print(random.choice(a))
    if (random.choice(a)) == (UI):
        print ('Tie')
        score_bot+1
        score_player+1
    elif 'rock' in (UI) and 'scissors' in (random.choice(a)):
        print ('You win!')
        score_player+1
    elif 'rock' in (UI) and 'paper' in (random.choice(a)):
        print ('You lose!')
        score_bot+1
    elif 'paper' in (UI) and 'scissors' in (random.choice(a)):
        print ('You lose!')
        score_bot+1        
    elif 'paper' in (UI) and 'rock' in (random.choice(a)):
        print ('You win!')   
        score_player+1 
    elif 'scissors' in (UI) and 'rock' in (random.choice(a)):
        print ('You lose!')
        score_bot+1
    elif 'scissors' in (UI) and 'paper' in (random.choice(a)):
        print ('You win!')
        score_player+1
        print (score_player)
        print (score_bot)
        if (score_bot) > (score_player):
            print ('bot wins!')
        elif (score_bot) < (score_player):
            print ('Player wins!')
```

[the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLf8j.png)

Comment: what is the error you are getting ? what are you expecting ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are never picking a random choice for the computer. Instead, you calculate a new random in every if statement.

Try:

```
computer_choice = random.choice(a)
```

And then replace every future `random.choice(a)` with `computer_choice`